# Select .Net Compiler 4.x in SharpDevelop

Tags: .net, sharpdevelop

as I currently have no admin rights on my machine, I'm using
`SharpDevelop-Portable`. Great tool, but the latest .NET version
I can select is 3.5.

The latest version installed on my machine is 4.0.

I did not find any settings to define the compiler.

Is it possible to define that compiler to use?
If not, is there a good, portable alternative to SharpDevelop

Regards,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry - found the latest version 5.x supporting up to .Net 4.5.2
This version is not called portable but also works finde without installation.